# Passing a child to container of parent type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent class **Individual** and child classes **Student** and **Professor** in my rails application.

Inheritance is handled with a gem called 'acts_as_relation' which simulates multiple table inheritance.

In addition, I have an action within which a student instance is appended to a list of individuals. Normally I would have expected this to go through without any problems but I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Individual(#70220161296060) expected, got Student(#70220161349360)
```

Here is a glance at my model:

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_superclass
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as :individual
end

class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as :individual
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this gem, but to give you some help, [here's what I've found](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation/issues/26) and [this](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation/issues/41):

> They both mention that you're calling an object through your relation, which will have confusion over polymorphism or similar. The two posts could not fix the issue, and I presume that is because they could find the correct object for their relationship

---

Looking at this further, I found [this tutorial on the gem homepage](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation#usage):

> `acts_as_relation` uses a polymorphic has_one association to simulate
>   multiple-table inheritance. For the e-commerce example you would
>   declare the product as a supermodel and all types of it as acts_as
>   :product (if you prefer you can use their aliases is_a and
>   is_a_superclass)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass
end

class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
end
```

> To make this work, you need to declare both a foreign key column and a
>   type column in the model that declares superclass. To do this you can
>   set :as_relation_superclass option to true on products create_table
>   (or pass it name of the association):

```
create_table :products, :as_relation_superclass => true do |t|
  # ...
end
```

> Or declare them as you do on a polymorphic belongs_to association, it
>   this case you must pass name to acts_as in :as option:

```
change_table :products do |t|
  t.integer :producible_id
  t.string  :producible_type
end

class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product, :as => :producible
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product, :as => :producible
end
```

Are you sure you've got your datatables set up correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am almost sure that there is nothing wrong with the database. After setting up the gem, I checked the functionality with rails console and insertions made into database are correct. According to the documentation, it is clear that both Book and Pen are extending ActiveRecord::Base, so this may be what is going wring here. The gem itself works fine until I want place a child in collection which is of parent type...

Comment: hmmmm - I wish I could help, but I don't have any experience with the gem sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solve this in my projects, is using `instance_ofsome_class.individuals << student_instance.individual`.

The thing here is that is not a real MTI, so your collection of individuals would accept only individuals instances. If you call `some_student_instance.individual` or `some_professor_instance.individual`, you'll get an individual instance which is related with your specific instance.
Then working with that collection, if you want a Student or Professor all you need to do is  call `individual_in_collection.specific`. For example:

```
p = Professor.create
a_model.individuals << p.individual
puts "#{a_model.individuals.first.class.name}"
=> Individual
puts "#{a_model.individuals.first.specific.class.name}"
=> Professor
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will indeed solve the problem but I am not interested in calling 'individual' on Professor, Student, or any other future descendants.